# Jquery - Toggle all slides on click event

Tags: jquery

Using jquery I have the function below. When the button is clicked it slides a div underneath that button, however there are multiple buttons on the page and if they click one button I want to make sure if any other buttons were clicked their div toggles back to sliding up so only one div is showing at any given time when a button is clicked. Any suggestions?

```
$('.ftable').delegate('.button.green.table','click',function() {

    ftableid = $(this).attr('title');

    $("#formtable" + ftableid).slideToggle("fast", function() {

        //code here

    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('.ftable').delegate('.button.green.table','click',function() {

      $(".button.green.table").slideUp(function () {



        ftableid = $(this).attr('title');

        $("#formtable" + ftableid).slideToggle("fast", function() {

            //code here

        });


}); 


        return false;

    });
```